# regular expression to completely remove html attribute from element

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using vb.net and my database is returning a string like this with a really long title attribute that I want to remove:

```
<img title="3497fh-39848f-04ghk38-483728_part1__book1_93822-3948329928"
```

I tried this regex:

```
<?(title).*?"^*?
```

but it's only getting "title=" part.  How can I find the title and everything else between the quotes?

Here is a [Regex Tester link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C%3F%28title%29.*%3F%22%5E*%3F&i=%3Cimg%20title%3D%223497fh-39848f-04ghk38-483728_part1__book1_93822-3948329928%22&r=)

I want to completely remove the title attribute.

thanks!

Comment: You sure you don’t want to use an HTML parser to parse HTML? https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @Ryan I actually have that installed already.  How would that make it easier to remove the title attribute?  Thanks

Comment: So you want to remove the title tag and everything inbetween it?

Comment: @Zaggler yes, I want it to just be the <img> tag without a title attribute.

Comment: `<?(title)="[^"]*"` that works. This removes the title and the data inbetween the tags...

Comment: @Zaggler thanks! That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `Regex`... Please see [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/wh0pXT/1) for more information on this `Regex`.

```
 <?(title)="[^"]*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only should resort to a regex to manipulate HTML if it is not syntactically correct and no other libraries can deal with it.

With [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (install the NuGet package), you may easily get all `a` tags and remove `title` attribute from them like this:

```
Dim s = "<img title=""3497fh-39848f-04ghk38-483728_part1__book1_93822-3948329928"">"
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(s)
RemoveAttributeFromTag(doc, "title")
Debug.Print(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml)
```

with the `RemoveAttributeFromTag` being:

```
Private Sub RemoveAttributeFromTag(html As HtmlDocument, AttName As String)
    Dim elements = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@" + AttName)
    For Each element In elements
        element.Attributes.Remove(AttName)
    Next
End Sub
```

This prints `<img>`:[image]

The means of last resort solution is

```
Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=<[_a-zA-Z][^<]*?)\s+style=""[^""]*""", "")
```

where

- `(?<=<[_a-zA-Z][^<]*?)` - a positive lookbehind making sure/requiring that immediately to the left of the current location, there is `<`, then an ASCII letter or `_` followed with any 0+ chars other than `<`, as few as possible, can be found
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `style="` -  a literal `style="` substring
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"`  - final `"`

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3c%5b_a-zA-Z%5d%5b%5e%3c%5d*%3f%29%5cs%2btitle%3d%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22&i=%3cimg+title%3d%223497fh-39848f-04ghk38-483728_part1__book1_93822-3948329928%22%3e&r=).