# Regex.Replace leaving behind one quotation mark

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have this regex below that does remove the desired attribute from the tag, but it leaves a quotation mark in it's place.

Here is the expression:

```
gameDescription = Regex.Replace(gameDescription, "<?(style)=""[^""]*", "")
```

I also tried this, but get the same result:

```
gameDescription = Regex.Replace(gameDescription, "<?(style)=""[^""]*", String.Empty)
```

So this:

```
<img id="123" style="padding: 4px;" src="mypics/1.png" />
```

becomes this:

```
<img id="123" " src="mypics/1.png" />
```

It's leaving one quotation mark in there and I can't figure out how to get rid of it?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you do not match it: `"<?(style)=""[^""]*"""`. But not that `<?` makes little sens here. I think you wanted to use `"(?<=<[_a-zA-Z][^<]*?)\s+style=""[^""]*"""`

Comment: You accepted a wrong answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724163). Have the person who answered fix it. Or let is be answered correctly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, your regex fixed the issue.  Thank you.  I'll delete this question.